# Change active directory server

Tags: active-directory

Situation is right now I have pc, and test server.

I don't have production server.

If I create domain on test server first, and let all pc join the domain.

What I need to do when production server is come?

I want to move test server out, and use production server as domain server.

Answer (score 1):

When you receive the production server you can promote it using DCPROMO so that the data is replicated and transfer the FSMO roles to the new server then demote the test server.

Comment: And by doing that I suppose both AD servers are masters, right?

Comment: I'm assuming you have 2008, here, where there's no real concept of a Master/Slave (or Primary/Backup as the terms were used) with Domain Controllers. That said, both servers will be authoritative for all sorts of requests and changes made on either will replicate to the other so they're 'Masters' in that sense, yes.